# What's the conditions that ensure this limit?

Tags: calculus, probability

I have this limit

$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} x F(x)$,

in which $F(x)$ is a cumulative probability function for a continuous random variable $X$. I would like to know the conditions that ensure this limit to be zero.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need $E|X| < \infty$. Here's why:

Let $Y = -X$ and $y=-x$, then the problem reduces to showing
$$\lim_{y \to \infty} yP(Y\geq y) = 0 $$

Now $E|X| < \infty \Rightarrow E|Y| < \infty$.

Since $y \to \infty$, for $y>0$, we have

$$0 \leq yP(Y\geq y) = y \int_y^\infty dF_Y(u) \leq \int_y^\infty udF_Y(u)$$

Now $\int_y^\infty udF_Y(u)$ is monotone decreasing in y, hence it has a limit. Observe that
$$ \int_y^\infty udF_Y(u) = E[Y] - \int_{-\infty}^y udF_Y(u)$$  (1)

Take limits on both sides to get $ \lim_{y \to \infty}\int_y^\infty udF_Y(u) = 0$

Thus the result follows. You just need $E|X| < \infty$ i.e. X is integrable.

......

Comment: Thank you! This explains what occurs with the Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand if $E[|x|]<\infty$ is a necessary condition to apply the Jensen's Inequality or is an implication.

Comment: I didn't use jensen's anywhere. $E|X| < \infty$ implies that $EY$ is finite and RHS of (1) is 0 in the limit. If not, you will get an $\infty - \infty$ sort of problem.

Comment: I see my mistake. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We know $F(x)$ is defined as $$ F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy$$
This means that
$$ x F(x) = \frac{F(x)}{1/x} =  \frac{\int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy}{1/x}$$

Using L`hopitals rule, the limit can be reduced to that of:

$$ -x^2 f(x) $$

So the condition we require is that $x^2 f(x) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Cool. See the Standard Cauchy: $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} x^2 f(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: This assumes existence of pdf i.e. cdf is differentiable.

Comment: Thanks @GautamShenoy.  I don't know much probability theory past basic first year stuff, I just assumed there was always an underlying pdf that we work with.

Comment: Not always. Unless it's stated "Continuous Random variable". Anyway glad to be of help.

Comment: I'm talking about continuous random variable. I will edit my post. Thank you, guys!

Comment: No worries. My proof works in general.